# Check to see if cURL is installed locally?

Tags: curl

How do I check if `cURL` is installed on my local server instance?

Does it matter what type of server I'm running to check it?

> Is it different if it's a PHP server or a CF server?

Comment: Do you mean libcurl or the command curl?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

In the Terminal, type:

$ `curl -V`

That's a capital `V` for the version

Comment: on windows 10/11 use  `curl.exe -V` - if  `curl -V` doesn't run

Answer (score 13):

cURL is disabled for most hosting control panels for security reasons, but it's required for a lot of php applications. It's not unusual for a client to request it. Since the risk of enabling cURL is minimal, you are probably better off enabling it than losing a customer. It's simply a utility that helps php scripts fetch things using standard Internet URLs.

To enable cURL, you will remove curl_exec from the "disabled list" in the control panel php advanced settings. You will also find a disabled list in the various php.ini files; look in /etc/php.ini and other paths that might exist for your control panel. You will need to restart Apache to make the change take effect.

## service httpd restart

To confirm whether cURL is enabled or disabled, create a file somewhere in your system and paste the following contents.

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(curl_version());
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Save the file as testcurl.php and then run it as a php script.

## php `testcurl.php`

If cURL is disabled you will see this error.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_version() in testcurl.php on line 2

If cURL is enabled you will see a long list of attributes, like this.

```
array(9) {
["version_number"]=>
int(461570)
["age"]=>
int(1)
["features"]=>
int(540)
["ssl_version_number"]=>
int(9465919)
["version"]=>
string(6) "7.11.2"
["host"]=>
string(13) "i386-pc-win32"
["ssl_version"]=>
string(15) " OpenSSL/0.9.7c"
["libz_version"]=>
string(5) "1.1.4"
["protocols"]=>
array(9) {
[0]=>
string(3) "ftp"
[1]=>
string(6) "gopher"
[2]=>
string(6) "telnet"
[3]=>
string(4) "dict"
[4]=>
string(4) "ldap"
[5]=>
string(4) "http"
[6]=>
string(4) "file"
[7]=>
string(5) "https"
[8]=>
string(4) "ftps"
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using XAMPP**

In the current version (?) of the xampp you cannot locate the curl_exec in the php.ini, just try using

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(curl_version());
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

and save to your htdocs. Next go to your browser and paste

```
http://localhost/[your_filename].php
```

if the result looks like this

```
array(9) {
  ["version_number"]=>
  int(469760)
  ["age"]=>
  int(3)
  ["features"]=>
  int(266141)
  ["ssl_version_number"]=>
  int(0)
  ["version"]=>
  string(6) "7.43.0"
  ["host"]=>
  string(13) "i386-pc-win32"
  ["ssl_version"]=>
  string(14) "OpenSSL/1.0.2e"
  ["libz_version"]=>
  string(5) "1.2.8"
  ["protocols"]=>
  array(19) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "dict"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "file"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "ftp"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "ftps"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "gopher"
    [5]=>
    string(4) "http"
    [6]=>
    string(5) "https"
    [7]=>
    string(4) "imap"
    [8]=>
    string(5) "imaps"
    [9]=>
    string(4) "ldap"
    [10]=>
    string(4) "pop3"
    [11]=>
    string(5) "pop3s"
    [12]=>
    string(4) "rtsp"
    [13]=>
    string(3) "scp"
    [14]=>
    string(4) "sftp"
    [15]=>
    string(4) "smtp"
    [16]=>
    string(5) "smtps"
    [17]=>
    string(6) "telnet"
    [18]=>
    string(4) "tftp"
  }
}
```

curl is enable

Answer (score 0):

Another way, say in CentOS, is:

```
$ yum list installed '*curl*'
Loaded plugins: aliases, changelog, fastestmirror, kabi, langpacks, priorities, tmprepo, verify,
              : versionlock
Loading support for Red Hat kernel ABI
Determining fastest mirrors
google-chrome                                                                                    3/3
152 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Installed Packages
curl.x86_64                                        7.29.0-42.el7                                @base
libcurl.x86_64                                     7.29.0-42.el7                                @base
libcurl-devel.x86_64                               7.29.0-42.el7                                @base
python-pycurl.x86_64                               7.19.0-19.el7                                @base
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want curl installed: just execute the install command and see what happens.

`$ sudo yum install curl`

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * epel: mirrors.kernel.org
 * extras: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * remi-php72: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
 * remi-safe: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
 * updates: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
Package curl-7.29.0-54.el7_7.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```